# SQL - WHERE clause with two different sets of conditions?

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-server-2016

I'm using Microsoft SQL management studio on SQL server 2016. I am trying to filter out some results from two separate sets of conditions. The first set does the heavy work, but I just need to add a second set of conditions that filter out just a few rows that actually are not filtered out by the first set of conditions. These other rows that need to be filtered have to meet the exact combination of extra criteria or otherwise too many rows will be filtered.

So I have this:

```
SELECT
    postdate
    ,costarea
    ,storeloc
    ,user
    ,movetype
    ,account
FROM table1
WHERE
--Condition 1
(postdate > '12/31/2015'
AND costarea <> 'None'
AND storeloc <> '50A')

OR

--Condition 2
(account <> '5500'
AND user <> 'JDOE'
AND movetype <> '405')
```

Basically, I need to filter the rows under condition 1 and then filter the few rows that would be filtered by condition 2 but are not filtered by condition 1 as they pass those conditions. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can make a column with a case statement:
CASE WHEN postdate> ' 12/31/2015' and [rest of conidition 1] THEN 'Condition 1' 
WHEN [condition 2] THEN 'Condition 2' END AS CONDITIONS_MET and use it to filter the results

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: @VvdL I didn't think you could filter from case statements like that in the where clause (unless I am misunderstanding)? Or do you just mean filter outside of SQL? That could work but I would prefer to do it within SQL.

Comment: @SalmanA That query doesn't filter the rows that meet the second condition since the rows I am filtering for the second condition are not filtered out by the first condition.

Comment: have you tried changing `OR` to `AND` ?

Comment: I am sorry but it is still not clear so I ma try again: you want rows that match set a or set b but not both at the same time?

Comment: @SalmanA Sorry, I may be having a hard time describing it, but that is correct. I want to pass everything through the first condition. Then pass everything through the second condition to filter the few rows that make it through the first condition but would then not make it through the second.

Comment: Then you just need to change OR to AND

Comment: @SalmanA and iSR5 That didn't appear to work, but I think I figured it out. I just put the first the condition in one select statement. Then I used that as a sub-query and and did the second where not on the select statement using that sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying for is...

```
where
   NOT (
         condition1
            or
         condition2
       )
```

But you would have to reverse the logic some by doing

```
where
   NOT
      (
         (   postdate < '2016-01-01'
         AND costarea = 'None'
         AND storeloc = '50A' )

            OR
         (   account = '5500'
         AND user = 'JDOE'
         AND movetype = '405')
      )
```

Comment: I think I have it set up like you have suggested, but it appears to be only doing the second filter? For example I am still seeing things listed with the costarea being None.

Comment: @scorbin, depends... If you have cost area of "GOOD", but the user is "JDOE", it would be excluded.  It passes on one condition but fails on the other, so it would be excluded in final set.  Your criteria is really strange for explicit NOTs of your original post.  Cant directly see / resolve based on info provided.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. I just put the first the condition in one select statement. Then I used that as a sub-query and and did the second where not on the select statement using that sub-query. Thanks for your help!